# If the value of a specific column from a previous date is greater than zero then True, less than or equal to zero is False

Tags: python, pandas

```
,clock_now,competition,market_name,lay,per_day
0,2022-12-30,A,B,-1.0,-1.0
1,2022-12-31,A,B,1.28,0.28
2,2023-01-01,A,B,-1.0,-0.72
3,2023-01-02,A,B,1.0,0.28
4,2023-01-03,A,B,1.0,1.28
5,2023-01-04,A,B,-1.0,-1.72
6,2023-01-04,A,B,-1.0,-1.72
7,2023-01-04,A,B,-1.0,-1.72
```

The idea is to get the value of the `per_day` column of the previous date closest to the row being analyzed.

For example:

In the lines with the date `2023-01-04`, check in any of the lines that have the date `2023-01-03` which is the value of the column `per_day`, if it is greater than zero, True, if it is less or equal to zero, False.

The list would look like this:

```
False
False
True
False
True
True
True
True
```

My attempt:

```python
df.clock_now = pd.to_datetime(df.clock_now)
df['invest'] = np.where(df.loc[df.clock_now == df['clock_now'] - timedelta(days=1),'per_day'].values[0] > 0,True,False)
```

But they all return `False` and there is another problem, it is not sure that the date will always be `1` day ago, it could be `2` or more, so it would still be a failed option.

How should I proceed in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby` to group together rows with the same date, aggregate with `last` to get last value, then `shift` by one to assign each date the value corresponding to previous date, then `join` back with original dataframe:

```python
df.join(df.groupby('clock_now').last()['per_day'].shift(1).rename('prev_day') > 0, on='clock_now')
```

This will output

```
   Unnamed: 0   clock_now competition market_name   lay  per_day  prev_day
0           0  2022-12-30           A           B -1.00    -1.00     False
1           1  2022-12-31           A           B  1.28     0.28     False
2           2  2023-01-01           A           B -1.00    -0.72      True
3           3  2023-01-02           A           B  1.00     0.28     False
4           4  2023-01-03           A           B  1.00     1.28      True
5           5  2023-01-04           A           B -1.00    -1.72      True
6           6  2023-01-04           A           B -1.00    -1.72      True
7           7  2023-01-04           A           B -1.00    -1.72      True
```